# CMD: program.exe 1< "A:/input.txt" yield no output

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

I've updated the question:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
cout << "cout argc: " << argc << endl;
cerr << "cerr argc: " << argc << endl;

cout << "cout usatty: " << _isatty(_fileno(stdin)) << endl;
cerr << "cerr usatty: " << _isatty(_fileno(stdin)) << endl;

if (argc == 1 && _isatty(_fileno(stdin)))
{
    cout << "cout Error: No space between num and <" << endl;
    cerr << "cerr Error: No space between num and <" << endl;
}
}
```

Cmd outputs:

```
program.exe 0< "A:/input.txt"
cout argc: 1
cerr argc: 1
cout usatty: 0
cerr usatty: 0

program.exe 1< "A:/input.txt"
cerr argc: 1
cerr usatty: 64
cerr Error: No space between num and <

program.exe 2< "A:/input.txt"
cout argc: 1
cout usatty: 64
cout Error: No space between num and <
```

Now I can detect <1 and <2 (but not differentiate between them) and <0 still goes undetected.

So two issues remain for me:

1) How can I print an error message that works with both <1 and <2

2) How do I detect <0

Answer (score 4):

C++ programs have three standard files open: Standard input at number `0`, standard output at number `1` and standard error at number `2` (C++ also have standard log with `std::clog`, but its the same as standard output, except it's not buffered).

What you're doing with `1<` is trying to redirect your input to standard *output*. This will of course not work.

When you have a space between `1` and `<`, as in `1 <`, then you pass the `1` as an argument to the program (which will be placed in `argv[1]`, the index is not related to the argument), and the redirection is to standard input.